# How to retrieve the folder ID of a shared folder with server-side java Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript

Having the folder name, when I try to get the folder ID of a local folder, my server-side java script code works well; but when the folder is a shared folder is not working.

Could you please advise on how to do it ?

This is my code:

```js
var req1 = Folder.Retrieve({Property:'Name',SimpleOperator:'equals',Value:'FolderName'});
var FolderID = req1[0].ID;
```

If the 'FolderName' is a folder on the Local folder structure all good. If  the folder is a shared folder not working.

Comment: I believe this will only work at the parent level of the folder. The context of the function is only for local. And technically on the local environment that folder does not exist. It exists at the parent level and that BU has 'access' to it. So you would not be able to find it in the shared BUs, only the one that created it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. What I really need is to be able to reference a shared folder for cloning data extensions into this shared folder. We are basically implementing an archival system. If I know the shared folder ID (and name), Could I reference this shared folder for creating a new data extension there using the WSProxy function: var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", ClonedDE); ?

Comment: I believe this would only be possible via the parent. You could place the script there to retrieve the DE and then create the new DE there. As a heads up, I have noticed in the past that creating shared DEs via API can have issues with them not showing up in the UI or similar issues.

Comment: Perfect. I will do that. Thanks for your recommendations !